# Automatically remove bounties when migrating

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties, migration, moderation

A question that is off topic and needs to be migrated *still needs to be migrated even when there is a bounty on it.*

Currently, if you attempt to migrate a question from the flag queue, if the question has a bounty on it, you must

1. open the question in a new tab
2. clear the bounty
3. migrate the question
4. close the tab
5. remove the flag from the queue or ignore it

I have *never* encountered a situation where I saw that an off-topic question shouldn't be migrated for the sole reason that it has a bounty on it.

**If a moderator attempts to migrate a question, any bounties on that question should be automatically removed.**

Comment: I firmly agree that a bounty is not a good reason to keep an off topic or bad question around. Closing a question, period, should automatically remove and refund a bounty if done by a moderator. Since we have the ability to do it in several steps, it makes sense to be able to do it in one.

Comment: My new plan: Ask a question, bounty it. If I don't get any good answers with 12 hours to go on the bounty, edit it to be off-topic and self-flag requesting migration

Comment: sure .. I follow ... but how common is this?

Answer (score 6):

We *want* this to be a manual step, so that a bounty isn't in any way overlooked when closing.  This is a conscious decision in the workflow, and a rare one to encounter.

Note we don't *completely prohibit* migrating a question with a bounty, but by making it a 2 step process, we make it a clear decision by the moderator.

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928534/tools-for-measuring-developers-work I've flagged this question as off-topic.  In my opinion, though, the question should simply be closed (at least while the bounty is in progress), or, if feasible, the bounty should remain even after it's migrated.

Comment: I remove the bounty for this fippery!  Since when does a bounty make, for example, an off-topic question on-topic?  The clear decision to migrate has already been made.  Its the same decision *we make every single time we migrate an off-topic question!*  The idea that because there is a bounty on a question, then our decision to migrate may be wrong is just nonsense.  Any fool can place a bounty on their own question.  This situation reminds me of people who place "PLEASE DO NOT MIGRATE THIS" at the top of their posts because *SO gets more traffic*.  Why not force us to edit before migration?