# Posts without notices showing up with hasnotice:yes

Tags: bug, status-completed, post-notices

I recently did a search here on MSE for [`hasnotice:yes locked:no`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasnotice%3Ayes+locked%3Ano). What surprised me is that two of the posts listed in this search have no notices... well, sort of. While there is no notice displayed on the post itself, the revision histories show that notices ("Notice added Draw attention by User") were added in 2011 and never removed:

- [Why don't all bugs and feature-requests have moderator status tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60505/323179) ([revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/60505/revisions))
- [Automatically remove bounties when migrating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100121/323179) ([revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/100121/revisions))

What happened here? Has this happened on other sites? It doesn't appear like these were typical bounties, as there is no "Bounty Started worth N reputation by User" notice in the history, and the "start bounty" option is available.

Can we fix it so that these posts don't show up searches for `hasnotice:yes`?

---

OK, I did some more searching, this time with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/795480/bounties-that-never-ended):

```sql
select postid as [Post Link], creationdate from posthistory 
where posthistorytypeid = 33 
 and postid not in (select postid from posthistory where posthistorytypeid = 34) --notice removed
 and postid not in (select postid from posthistory where posthistorytypeid = 14) --locked
```

(This query also returns questions that were ongoing as of the last update of SEDE.)

What I found is that yes, this has happened before, and with other bounty reasons (e.g. "Notice added Authoritative reference needed by User", "Notice added Improve details by User"). As animuson says, these look like bounties that were ended prematurely, as I found some questions that seem to have been closed while there was an ongoing bounty:

- [Infragistics WPF and WinForms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7454332/6083675) ([revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7454332/revisions))
- [How main method called without calling it by classname.mainmethod()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7579474/6083675) ([revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7579474/revisions))

Comment: Hmm both of those questions had the bounties removed before their usual expiration. Might be an artifact of how old bounties got removed from a question by moderator (didn't properly remove the post notice entry too)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

animuson answered this in a comment already: for a brief period of time, the notices created along with bounties weren't automatically removed if the bounty was revoked by a moderator.

Notices were *added* to the bounty system on September 19th, 2011; the logic to remove them upon revocation was added on November 22nd, 2011. So for about two months, any revoked bounties would have to have had their notices removed manually; apparently, that never happened for these two questions.

I've done so now; they no longer appear in search results.

---

Additionally, there were 12 similarly-afflicted questions on Stack Overflow; I've removed those notices as well (the additional 30 or so that'd long ago been deleted I left alone).

Rounding out the rest of the network, I removed...

- 1 notice on Super User
- 1 notice on Ask Different
- 1 notice on Unix & Linux (notable because it was on *[question number 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-i-use-dd-to-migrate-data-from-an-old-drive-to-a-new-drive)*)
- and 4 notices from Ask Ubuntu

This should thoroughly resolve the problem.

Comment: OK, but this also happened on other sites. I wrote an [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/795480/bounties-that-never-ended) to find them (I was adding this information to my question when you answered, BTW).

Comment: See edit, @Laurel